# How to update a record outside a database transaction in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a long-running background job that updates multiple database records, so I have it enclosed in a database transaction. I also have a `JobStatus` database record with a `percent_complete` field that is used to let the user know how far along the background job is to being complete. While the background job is running, the website polls the server to get the `percent_complete` value from the associated `JobStatus` record.

In the background job that is wrapped in a database transaction, how do I update the `JobStatus` record outside of the database transaction so the current `percent_complete` value is returned when the website polls?

```rb
class BackgroundJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(job_status_id)
    job_status = JobStatus.find(job_status_id)
    job_status.update(percent_complete: 0)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      # ... update some records
      job_status.update(percent_complete: 25)
      # ... update some more records
      job_status.update(percent_complete: 50)
      # ... update some more records
      job_status.update(percent_complete: 75)
      # ... finish updating records
      job_status.update(percent_complete: 100)
    end
  end
end
```

How do I only have the updates to the `job_status` record be outside the database transaction?

I'm using Ruby on Rails version 7.0

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use a different DB connection for your `JobStatus` model than the connection that's in a transaction. There are a few ways to check out your own connection manually from the pool, [explained here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html), but then you have some annoying code using raw SQL to make the update.

Personally, I would use the [Multiple Database stuff](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html) and set your `JobStatus` model up to inherit from a separate class with a `connects_to` to ensure it uses a different DB connection (to the same DB):

So:

### database.yml

```yaml
development:
  primary: &primary
    your: db
    details: here
  job_status:
    <<: *primary
```

### app/models/job_status_abstract.rb

```rb
class JobStatusAbstract < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true

  connects_to database: { writing: :job_status }
end
```

### app/models/job_status.rb

```rb
class JobStatus < JobStatusAbstract

  # ...rest of your model
```